# Why isn't my UPDATE sql query working? Will not update table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

Is there something wrong with my function here? I've created a simple task manager with a blog page as well. This is the same function I use to update Tasks in the `task` table, just modified to update the `Blog` table instead.

```
function update_blog($blogpost) {
    global $db;

    $sql = "UPDATE Blog SET ";
    $sql .= "blog_date='" . db_escape($db, $blogpost['blog_date']) . "', ";
    $sql .= "blog_content='" . db_escape($db, 
    $blogpost['blog_content']) . "' ";
    $sql .= "WHERE id='" . db_escape($db, $blogpost['id']) . "' ";
    $sql .= "LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    if($result) {
      return true;
    } else {
      // UPDATE failed
      echo mysqli_error($db);
      db_disconnect($db);
      exit;
    }
}
```

From `edit.php`, the user is redirected to `blog.php` upon submitting their blog post edits. However, the edits are not seen and the table itself is not updated. Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: checked for errors?

Comment: Is `$result` true or false?  What is the actual runtime SQL query being executed?  What happens when you execute that query manually?

Comment: try to echo the sql before execute it and verify it

Comment: did u output the raw query? and see its what u want?

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur, even with the escape string functions**

Comment: @David $result is true, or else it wouldn't be redirecting to blog.php. How can i execute the query manually? New to all of this! Thanks for your patience

Comment: @MichaelTrieb: First you'll want to find out what the query actually *is*.  Echo or log the value of `$sql` somewhere.  Examine that value and see if it's actually what you expect it to be.  If so, use whatever tools you use to manage your MySQL database (command line, or any graphical tools you've installed) to execute that query.  Are any rows updated?  If you copy that same `WHERE` clause to a `SELECT` statement, are any rows found?

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with a record with `db_escape($db, $blogpost['id'])` not being present in the database (if the query is not failing). I would recommend executing a simple `SELECT` to see how many rows exist, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Blog
WHERE id = <value of db_escape($db, $blogpost['id'])>;
```

If you don't get any rows, that probably means there is no record present and hence, no update. You might have to pass different value in that case, depending on what you have in the form.